# Posts being replaced/deleted

Tags: posts

As far as I know this is not theme specific, but something which has just started going weird on my WP site. I'm asking for advice on what could cause this problem.

I've set up a site using this theme http://themeforest.net/item/serpent-responsive-social-network-theme/2598368

The theme has a front end posting option so users can register and then post.

Everything was going fine until I noticed that one of the posts had disappeared from the front page. By this time there were 7 posts and there should of been 8. I had gotten an email saying that there was a post waiting for moderation, so I went to look at the new post, and even though the text content was different somehow it was using the featured image from the post that had been deleted! At the time I thought it was the author of the deleted post that had come back and changed the original post but it turned out it was a completely new author/post.

So that was when I knew something was wrong. I approved that post so I had 8 posts again. Then someone else posted, and I noticed that last post had been deleted! it wasn't anywhere in the admin posts section.

I've taken the site offline to try and understand what's going on.

As far as I know there is no setting in WP that restricts the number of posts? and it's really weird how it deletes/removes the last post, where could I look in the .php files to find out whats going wrong?

Could a plug-in be causing the issue?

My site also automatically updated to the latest version just a day ago (3.7.1 I think) could that have issues?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *As far as I know this is not theme specific.* how have you verified this? does it also happen with a default theme active? considering that it's a premium theme, we can't see the code that is enabling this front-end posting mechanism. have you tried the theme author's support?

Comment: Of course but he says of course it doesn't cause that. I was just wondering where to start looking for the cause of such a problem.